# Spark RDD any() and all() methods?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have an `RDD[T]` and a predicate `T => Boolean`.
How do I calculate if all of items fit/do-not-fit the predicate?

Of course I can do it like this:

```
rdd
 .map(predicate)
 .reduce(_ && _)
```

but this will take full collection to iterate, that is an overkill.

I tried another approach which worked good for *local[1]*, but seemed to iterate a through everything on a real cluster too:

```
rdd
 .map(predicate)
 .first()
```

[Fails with exception if can't find any of required]

What is the canonical way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
def forAll[T](rdd:RDD[T])(p:T => Boolean): Boolean = {
  rdd.aggregate(true)((b, t) => b && p(t), _ && _)
}
```

As a side note, there's no real way to terminate early in spark, you send a job to the cluster and it executes. Aggregate is just a nice way to do what you want.

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and my option(1)? Why would aggregate stop on first 'false'?

Comment: @IlyaSmagin I see you're point now. There's no real way to terminate early in spark, you send a job to the cluster and it executes. Aggregate is just a nice way to do what you want.

Comment: would you like to post that separate so I could mark it as an answer?